# Push vertices of an OBJ file- Edit .obj

Tags: matlab, .obj, vertices, wavefront, meshlab

I have a .obj 3D model where I want to move some of the surface vertices for a given length.
How can I get to do this.
For smaller files I can just open it in the notepad and edit the vertices position. But when the model gets bigger this becomes impossible.

Matlab? Tried to load a 3D model which is kinda big using a toolbox. It takes a lot of time :( 
Meshlab maybe? -Couldn't find
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

With meshlab, you could write a plugin to manipulate yout mesh vertex.
So if you search a progamming solution, it could be a good choice.